Proving the divergence of $\int_0^{\infty } \frac{1}{| \log (\log (-x) \log (x))| } \, dx$
Can someone help to show that the following is divergent?
$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{1}{| \log (\log (-x) \log (x))| } \, dx$$
Graph looks like this, limit at $x = 0$ is $0$:

Edit: The graph is not accurate. The integrand blows up at $x=1$, but the integral looks divergent numerically even in $2$ to ${\infty }$ range.

Well to me looks like $\log(-x)$ is defied for $x<0$ and $\log(x)$ is defied for $x>0$ so the function you're trying to integrate has an empty domain...

For $x < 0$, $log$ becomes complex valued, and because of the presence of Abs, the integrand becomes real valued
